# Installed Ruby 1.9.3 manually, but ruby -v shows no such file or directory

Tags: ruby, centos, ruby-1.9.3

On `CentOS`, I did a manual install of `Ruby 1.9.3` from a tar file. I received no errors during the `./configure` make and make install.

```
"which ruby" outputs "/usr/local/bin/ruby"

"whereis ruby" outputs "ruby: /usr/lib/ruby /usr/lib64/ruby /usr/local/bin/ruby /usr/local/lib/ruby"

"ruby -v" outputs "-bash: /usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory"
```

`echo $PATH` outputs `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/dell/srvadmin‌​/bin:/opt/dell/srvadmin/sbin:/root/bin` so it appears `/usr/local/bin` is before `/usr/bin`

Comment: Have you checked if the '/usr/bin/ruby' exists ? and if you user has rights on it ?

Comment: Thanks Up_One, '/usr/bin/ruby' does not exist. I guess I'm at a loss as to how to get ruby to see where the install was placed.

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit your `PATH` environment variable to look in `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin`.

See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/102932/adding-a-directory-to-path-in-centos) for details.

Simplest is to edit/create `~/.profile` with the line:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

which adds that directory to be the first it looks in. (And then either create a new shell, or `source ~/.profile` to re-run the commands in it.)

**Edit**: If `/usr/local/sbin` (the first item in your `PATH`) has a symlink for `ruby` pointing to `/usr/bin/ruby`, you should either remove this file, or create a new symlink, e.g.

```
$ cd /usr/local/sbin
$ sudo rm ruby
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/ruby
$ ls -l ruby
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  root  19 Mar 18 09:01 ruby -> /usr/local/bin/ruby
```

Comment: Thanks Phrogz, echo $PATH outputs '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/dell/srvadmin/bin:/opt/dell/srvadmin/sbin:/root/bin'

So it appears /usr/local/bin is before /usr/bin

Comment: @deluxe And in that same shell that gives you that result you are typing just `ruby -v` and it is responding with `/usr/bin/ruby`? That seems very surprising. Do you have a `/usr/local/bin/ruby`? Does it work, e.g. `/usr/local/bin/ruby -v`?

Comment: yeah all happening in the same shell.  So I ran /usr/local/bin/ruby -v and it shows me the appropriate version of ruby that was installed.  Does this imply that I should be good to go?

Comment: @deluxe That shows you that it was installed properly and is working. We still need to fix it so that `ruby` invokes the correct executable. Look in `/usr/local/sbin`: is there a `ruby` file, that is perhaps a symlink file pointing to `/usr/bin/ruby`? If so, delete that file, or change it to be a link to `/usr/local/bin/ruby`. (See my edited answer.)

Comment: well this seems a bit odd. `ls -la` in `/usr/local/sbin` shows me 0 files, but says 'total 8'.  There is no ruby file in there that is listed though.

Comment: I don't know why you would possibly be getting `/usr/bin/ruby` when there exists a `ruby` in a directory earlier in your `PATH`. At this point this feels like a CentOS issue, which I do not know and which is off-topic for Stack Overflow. However, this is entirely appropriate for http://unix.stackexchange.com/. I'm going to recommend that it be moved there.

Comment: so instead of making the symlink in `/usr/local/sbin`, I made a symlink in `/usr/bin/ruby`, where the version check was attempting to look. Creating that symlink gives me the appropriate response when typing `ruby -v`, thanks again for your help Phrogz!